# Require Module is undefined

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I have a module 'C 'that I already require in module 'A'. I can access module 'C' in module 'A'.
My new Module 'B' also requires that module. The implementation of 'B' is the same as in 'A', but my new module gets an undefined module back.

module B (js/controller/delete.js):

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'views/Box/BrowserView'
], function($, _, Backbone, browser){

alert(browser.created);            //alert -> can't read created of undefined

[...]

});
```

module A (js/mainView.js):

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'views/Box/BrowserView',
'jqm',
'socketio'
], function($,_, Backbone, browser){

    alert(browser.created)      //alerts false (browser is required)

});
```

Module C (js/views/Box/BrowserView.js)

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'text!templates/template.html',
'Controller/delete',
'jqm'
], function($,_,Backbone, bvtemp, delete){

var created = false;
[...}

return{
    [...],
    created : created
}
```

Edit: Require-Configuration

```
var require = {
paths: {
    overrides   :'overrides',
    jquery      :'libs/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min',
    underscore  :'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
    backbone    :'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
    //
    jqm         :'libs/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min',
    socketio    :'libs/socketio/socket.io',
    webSocket   :'websocket/socketConnection',
    text        :'text',
    templates   :'templates'
},
shim: {
    'overrides'  : {deps: ['jquery']},
    'backbone'   : {deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],exports: 'Backbone' },
    'jqm'        : {deps: ['jquery'],              exports: 'jqm'},
    'underscore' : {                               exports: '_'},
    'websocket'  : {deps:['socketio']},
    'templates'  : {deps: ['jqm']}
}};
```

[image]

Comment: are jquery underscore and backbone defined?

Comment: yes, they are defined and I can use them.

Comment: can you try to add jqm to the define array, to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: godd iead, but still undefined.

Comment: can you somehow share this code?

Comment: It's difficult because it's a phonegap application

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43127/discussion-between-ekeren-and-marcel)

Comment: There's nothing in the code shown that seems wrong to me. Seeing the configuration passed to RequireJS might help.

Comment: Is it a problem, that I have defined module a in module c?

Comment: kind of off topic - not really a great idea using the name 'delete'.

Comment: it's just for use here, my file is named projectBoxDeleteCtrl

Comment: It's easier to read if I name it just delete

Comment: Ok. And are you returning a definition from each of your dependencies? It's really hard to gauge the nature of problems like this with incomplete code.

Comment: Yes, Phonegap Apps are a pain. You can't post the projects on fiddle, cause they dont work there

Comment: Can you post your requireJS config?  This could be a directory issue.  How is your `baseUrl` defined... explicitly or implicitly?

Comment: I added it to the question as edit

Comment: Hmm, can you post your directory structure as well?

Comment: UP. I renamed the filenames in my example. They are a little bit different to my filestructure

Comment: Hmmm.  It's a little hard to follow along what you've called these files in the question vs what's in your actual file structure.  So is /js/Controller/deleteFile.js **Module B**?  And is /js/views/ProjectBox/projectBoxBrowserView.js **Module C**?  And in your posted code, does **Module C** actually require **Module B**, which itself requires **Module C**?  In other words, is there a cyclical dependency there?